# Wordpress query to display content if post count is greater than 1

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Working on a project and trying to write a query that will display certain content if there is more that 1 post in the post type. If there is only 1 post available it would display something different. Below is a trimmed down version of the query I built so far, just not certain how to implement counting the number of posts first.

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=event'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>    
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**UPDATE:** *updating my original post to reflect the shortcode I use instead. Basically what I am trying to do is have the query first check to see how many published posts are in the events post type, if total is greater than one post, the div layout will have a specific class, if there is only one post available, then it would use a different class.*

```
add_shortcode( 'events', 'callback_function_name' );

function callback_function_name( $atts, $shrt_content = null ) {

$atts = shortcode_atts(array(
    'category' => ''
), $atts, 'events');

$categories  = ! empty( $atts['category'] ) ? explode( ',' , $atts['category'] ) : '';

extract( $atts );   

$query_args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'event',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'meta_key'          => 'event_date',
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'tax_query'         => array( array(
                                'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                                'field'     => 'slug',
                                'operator'  => 'AND',
                                'terms'     => $categories
                            ) )
    );

$post_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

ob_start();


if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        
    <?php while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) : $post_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div id="event">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php 
}

$retVal = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

return $retVal; 
}
```

Comment: Is the desire to have a different class on the `<div id="event">` element depending on whether there is only 1 event post or multiple?

Comment: that is correct.. Bascially on the homepage of the website I am building it will have a section for upcoming events, but set to only show 2 posts - side by side at 50% width and class (controlled by the div) If there is only 1 upcoming event - I want it to use a different class for the div making it 100% wide. Hopefully this makes sense. I did figure out how to make it work on one of the php templates I built using <?php if(count($posts) >= 3) : ?>, but can't figure out how to incorporate that into the shotcode.

Comment: I updated my answer below. You can use a ternary in the `class=""` of the `<div id="event">` to either give it a class when more than 1 event or else use another class. Classes are up to you of course - I just provided generic classes of `half-width` and `full-width`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way to query posts is to use `WP_Query`. Then `$found_posts` will retrieve the total number of posts found matching the current query parameters.

Reference: [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'event'
);

$events_query = new WP_Query($args);

while ($events_query->have_posts()) : $events_query->the_post(); 

  // Get number of posts in query
  $number_of_events = $events_query->found_posts;

  <div id="event" class="<?php echo ($number_of_events > 1 ? 'half-width' : 'full-width'); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>

endwhile;
```

Comment: I updated my original post (see above) to see if it makes better sense. Any ideas on how would I go about utilizing the answer above - $number_of_events = $events_query->found_posts; inside of the shortcode I provided.

Comment: Thanks so much for the assistance, this really helped and out me in the right direction..